# Why is stft(istft(x)) ≠ x?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, pytorch

Why is stft(istft(x)) ≠ x?

Using PyTorch, I have computed the short-time Fourier transform of the inverse short-time Fourier transform of a tensor.
I have done so as shown below given a tensor `x`.
For `x`, the real and imaginary part are equal, or the imaginary part is set to zero -- both produces the same problem.

```
torch.stft(torchaudio.functional.istft(x, n_fft), n_fft)
```

As shown in the image, only a single one of the stripes in the tensor remains after applying `stft(istft(x))` -- all other stripes vanish.
If `stft(istft(x))` (bottom) was equal to `x` (top), both images would look similar.
Why are they so different?
It seems like `stft(istft(x))` can pick up only certain frequencies of `x`.

[x (top) and stft of istft of x (bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDrns.png)

I have also tried the same with `scipy.signal.istft` and `scipy.signal.stft` which causes the same issue.
Moreover, I have tried it with a wide range of tensors `x`, e.g., different randomized distributions, images, and other stripes.
Also, I have tried a variety of hyper-parameters for stft/istft.
Only for `x` generated by a short-time Fourier transform from a sound wave, it works.

Comment: I am trying the same with audio signals and the problem remains the same. Cannot reconstruct the audio back from the istft. The output is a simple cracking noise. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: After posting this comment. I looked into this blog [link](https://www.audiolabs-erlangen.de/resources/MIR/FMP/C8/C8S1_SignalReconstruction.html) and found that this works. They indeed have given a very nice explanation there as well. I tried it on audio files. It works, although the reconstrcted output is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short-time Fourier transform produces a more data than there is in the original signal.  Where a signal has N real samples, then STFT might have 4N complex samples -- 8 times more data.

It follows that the ISTFT operation must discard 7/8 of the data you provide it.

Most of the data in a STFT is redundant, and if you just make up values for all of the data, it is unlikely to correspond to a real signal.

In that case, an implementation of ISTFT will probably use a least-squares fit or other method of producing a signal with an STFT that matches your data as closely as possible, but it won't always be close.